# How can I take away editing privileges after a specific number of cells in a row have content?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sign up sheet for a class where there is a table with the names of the participants for the columns and the date of the classes are the rows. There is a class around once a week but only ten people can sign up. To signup, they just have to simply put an x in the table where the date and their name lineup. How can I restrict everyone from putting an x after the ten spots are filled in the row?

Comment: What have you tried thusfar?  As this is tagged for VBA, please include your attempt at coding, the issue/error you are having, and location of the issue, by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58401374/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options you could use once you detect the class has reached its limit:

- Use [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) to save as a read-only file.
  This, of course, can be defeated by a student browsing to the file in the file explorer and removing the read-only restriction.
- Use [`Worksheet.Protect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect) to restrict editing on the worksheet in question.
  You can even program it to use a password to protect the worksheet if you're worried about a student trying to un-protect it. Of course, the student could also open the code and find the password you used. But you can also password protect the VBA code itself if you're worried about that.